# Why won't 'usb debugging' mode stay on?

Tags: usb-debugging

I'm trying to put my phone into usb debugging mode, but it won't work. I'll turn it on, and it will turn off right away.. Has anyone else gone through this?

I'm running 2.3.4 on a zte score.

Comment: Is the phone plugged in at the time?  That could be the problem.

Comment: I've tried it plugged in, and not plugged in.

Comment: Have you tried a different USB cable?  I think I've had issues with a certain one that was flaky. Also try a different USB port on your computer.

Comment: I'll have to look around.. I'm not sure if I have another cable. And yes, I've tried both ports. But really, I think it is due to my phone.

Comment: my samsung galaxy fit (android 2.2.1) has the opposite problem: Every time i plugin usb usb-debugging is reenabled again. I need to switch it off because my laptop has problems with the usb-board and sometimes crashes when there is too much usb-activity. So i always switch usb debugging off on my phone so my laptop crashes once a week instead twice a day :-(

Comment: That's odd.. I'm not sure how a laptop could crash from that...

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with Huawei P Smart (today on Android Oreo).  Revoking USB debug permissions enabling USB debugging and then re-attaching it with 'transfer files' option, followed by accepting the PC certificate fingerprint appeared to work - at least for the time being.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue with my Mate 20x. Someone suggested that enabling Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode would keep the debugging switch on and it did the trick.