# How to permanently enable ADB in Huawei devices?

Tags: adb, huawei

I bought a huawei p30 for development purposes. So the first thing i did, it is enable development mode, enable adb over usb, then type `adb devices`... nothing!

When I enable adb over usb, the setting is not saved! If I go back, and then enter the developer menu, it's disabled again!

I found this workaround:

1. Dial `*#*#2846579#*#*`
2. Select background
3. Select USB mode
4. Select "Google mode"
5. Open settings
6. Find development options
7. Enable ADB over USB.

Now it works... for a little while! Just unplug the cable for 1 second, and I need to repeat all the steps again! ADB disabled, USB mode reverted to "huawei mode", and so on! This is ridiculous! I bought this device for development purposes, it should have a permanent way to enable adb, as expected in each single Android device since version 1.0. How devs can debug huawei devices if each time enabling adb is such an hassle???

I must be missing something, how to permanently enable adb on (newest?) Huawei devices?

Comment: There are apps in PlayStore that can directly open Development Option page. Not sure if they work on your device but worth a try as this would reduce the number of necessary steps. Another option would be not to disconnect the device from USB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using Huawei mate 10 lite, as I remember I had fixed this issue by selecting `Allow ADB debugging in charge only mode` at developer options section

Comment: It works! Thanks! I did not imagine that it was somewhat related

Comment: me too :) you are welcome